# java - web service client does not see the method arguments

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I create a bottom up web service on axis2 1.4.1 and tomcat 6.20 with a simple method such as

```
int helloWorld(int op1, int op2) {
   return op1 + op2;
}
```

and then I edit the services.xml file and include this method like this:

```
<operation name="helloWorld">
     <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" /> </operation>
```

Then I create a web service client on Eclipse IDE. THe problem is that even though I can see the method on the client, the method appears to accept no arguments.

How should I change the configuration to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: Did you use the Java2WSDL utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis2 works by reflection, so I suspect you need to make that method public.